# URL connection HTTP POST connection refused

Tags: java, http, url, connection

I am working on a Java desktop application with Java 7. For my application, I want to send data with POST to a server (using HTTP). The server is running on my local machine on localhost. 
But if I am trying to connect to the server, an connection reset (SocketTimeoutException) is returned. I can`t connect, I have also tried to connect to a webpage like http://www.google.de, but it also fails. The var body contains the POST data in correct form. (I have also tried to connect with disabled firewall)
My code:

```
body=body.substring(0,body.length()-2);
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    if (revision){ //Connect to the revision server
        this.urlRevision = new URL(this.settingsRevision.getAddress());
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlRevision.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(body.length()));
        connection.connect();
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(body);
        writer.flush();

        this.returnedData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        for(String line; (line = returnedData.readLine()) != null;){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        writer.close();
        this.returnedData.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
        this.exception=e;
}
```

Comment: Please try http://localhost in browser. Some other server may be running. What is your server?

Comment: Localhost is working in my browser, I am getting to the startpage of my local xampp server (apache server)

Comment: Working with: System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try close the connection like this:

```
} finally {
    if(connection != null) {
      connection.disconnect(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added this, but the SocketTimeoutException occurred again.

Comment: Can you connect without POST any data?

Answer (score 0):

I have already added it to the comments:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

Reason: Java is using IPv6 functions on my computer but IPv4 is used for internet connection (on my computer and by my provider (T-Online)).